# Test antivirus with virus/malware (No EICAR)

Tags: malware, antivirus

I am currently testing a new AI/Machine Learning antivirus solution. I installed it on a laptop and i manage through the dashboard on a different laptop. I am now testing how quickly it picks up stuff and how it alerts the administrator. An EICAR file won't work due to the way this particular antivirus works (if it doesn't try to harm your pc or includes harmful material it won't do anything). I've moved a few shell scripts that i wrote which picked them up as unsafe but now i want to try using real viruses and malware. Which is the safest way to do this? I've had a look around but when i visited most sites they were talking about EICAR which won't work.

Comment: Where to downloaded viruses is easy: tons of repos out there, and Github has a huge collections

Comment: As for how to test safely: use a VM.

Comment: I agree with what @schroeder said, however it can take long to find the malware on github. A specialized site: https://www.connect-trojan.com/